# Bing Maps Drawing Tools Module

Tags: bing-maps

We are using Ricky Brundritt Drawing Tools Module for Bing Maps V7. Is there a Bing Maps V8 version of this ? Since we are unable to draw shapes using this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bing Maps V8 has drawing tools built in. Use that instead of the old drawing tools module I created for V7  (old one does not work as good as built in one in V8). Here is some resources:

https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#DrawingTools_Basic

https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#dtDrawThings+JS

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt750543.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750468.aspx