# Unable to draw in Bing Maps V8 using DrawingToolsModule.js

Tags: bing-maps

We are unable to draw a polygon using Bing Maps V8 and DrawingToolsModule.js by Ricky Brunditt.

In the example in plunker(https://plnkr.co/edit/p2wvnvmhjv6P7ahdEJKS?p=options) we call the following method to show tool bar.

```
Toolkit.prototype.init = function () {

        var _toolkit = this;
        $('.toolkit-edit, .redo-search-wrap').hide();
        $('.toolkit-polygon').on('click', function (e) {
            _toolkit.drawingTools.getShapeLayer().clear();
            // hide extra buttons
            $('.toolkit-circle, .toolkit-edit, .toolkit-map-controls, .redo-search-wrap').hide();
            // show drawing instructions
            $('.message-search-wrap').show();
            // enter drawing mode
            _toolkit.drawingTools.setDrawingMode("polygon");
        });
```

when the user is finished drawing, we call the event in map.js:-

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'mouseup', function (e)
                {
                    //alert(e.keyCode);
                    //alert("mapclick");
                    document.onmouseup = function keypress(f) {

                        drawingTools.setDrawingMode(null);
                        $(".toolkit-circle, .toolkit-edit, .toolkit-polygon, .toolkit-map-controls, .redo-search-wrap").show();
                        $(".message-search-wrap").hide();
                        hideInfoBox();
                    }
                });
```

However, we are just not able to draw anything on maps. Let us know if we are missing something.

I attached the plunker at: https://plnkr.co/edit/p2wvnvmhjv6P7ahdEJKS?p=options

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bing Maps Drawing Tools Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231641/bing-maps-drawing-tools-module)

Comment: @rbrundritt - The above link does solve the problem.